# HapiJS Catbox: How to search a key using some value's fields as search criteria?

Tags: caching, hapi.js

In my app when a user is authenticated, I store his session data (including his email) in the server cache, and I create a sessionId that I use as the key.

When a user is deleted from the database, I want to check if he was logged in, that is, if there is a session in the cache that comes from his account, so I can drop that entry from the server cache too.

The problem is that the sessionId is not part of the User model, so I have to lookup his entry from the cache using his email, get the associated key, and drop the entry. Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catbox is just a key/value store and it doesn't look like there is a way to iterate through cache items like you want and find a user by another property. You need to know the key. You can either make the key the users' email or store sessionId in the database in another table.

You might be doing more work than you have to for session management. [Yar](https://github.com/hapijs/yar) is a hapi plugin that provides session management for you. [Invalidating a session](https://github.com/hapijs/yar/issues/98) is pretty simple as well.

> When the user logs out use `yar.reset()` to clear out the session.

[Hapi-auth-cookie](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie) is another plugin for cookie-based session management.

Comment: I really hoped that there could be away for reverse lookup with catbox, I will find a work around.

Comment: I understand the point with Yar and Hapi-auth-cookie. In fact I am building an API, and I will issue JWT token to authenticated users, but I don't want my API session logic to be tied to a type of client. For My server (API), being authenticated means coming with a valid token, as long as that token match with something in the cache, if not we return a 401, and it is up to the client to manage. For my web client I will use Yar or Hapi-auth-cookie to keep the token. I will certainly use something else for my android client.

Comment: The token contains the sessionId in question.

Comment: Since I am using catbox-mongodb strategy, I can directely remove the document from the database, with the appropriate query. Is that allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally created a **pre** that return all the sessionIds associated to the account to be deleted, so I can delete them normally with `server.cache.drop(key, cb)`. Error handling removed for brevity.

```
function currentSessionIds(request, reply) {
  const sessionIds = [];

  User.findOne({ _id: request.params.id }, (err, user) => {
    const cacheDB = request.server.app.sessionsCache._cache.connection.settings.partition;

    MongoClient.connect(`mongodb://host:port/${cacheDB}`, (err, db) => {
      db.collection('sessions').find({ 'value.account.email': user.email }, { _id: 1 }).toArray((err, sessions) => {   
        sessions.forEach(session => sessionIds.push(session._id));
        reply(sessionIds);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

But of course this solution is too tied to mongodb and the way catbox-mongodb strategy store the data. If they change it my function is down.